My Object Isn't Showing Up When I Import It!
I've successfully downloaded many 3D objects off different sites (mainly SketchFab) and viewed them in File Explorer and other programs, but when I try to import them into Blender, they appear in the blender file view but are faded and don't open when I click on them.
I did some research and found out how to install add-ons. I did so with the SketchFab add-on and successfully imported it into the scene collection bar. But it didn't appear in the grid user perspective. When I selected it in the scene collection bar, it showed a miny orange dot (probably the file minimized to the dot).
I did some more research and tried many different suggested methods such as clicking the (.) or delete button to center on my object or changing the size of the objects in the dimensions tab, but nothing worked. I even tried saving my 3D files as different file types, but nothing worked.

Blender does not open external formats with the same dialogue as its own format. You have to choose File -> Import -> {the correct file format}. As for the orange dot, that is the object’s origin, and will show no matter how big or small the object is. Speaking of which, it is far more likely that the object is too big rather than too small. Considering that you also made several severe terminology mistakes (for example, one doesn’t import an addon), I have little doubt that the Sketchfab addon is working correctly, but you are somehow not following the instructions for finding the imported model in your scene correctly. What were the dimensions of the model shown in the Item tab of the 3D Viewport editor Sidebar? If they weren’t all zero, there is some geometry there. You also didn’t say what you changed them to, so we have no idea if that was effective or not. When someone said to press [Numpad . / Delete] to frame the selected object, they did not mean to press the period key or the regular delete key, but rather the decimal point key on your number pad. Pressing regular period only works if you have Emulate Numpad turned on in settings. If you don’t have a number pad on your keyboard, just use Shift + C instead, as the effect is similar.

Additionally to pressing Numpad . it might help to press A beforehand to select all, to make sure there is something selected to center the view on (although after importing the model should be selected by default). Shift+C on the other hand does not care if something is selected. @TheLabCat Of course I know you know that, it is just an additional tip for Samuel.
